# Create a date, insert it into database, compare, it's different

Tags: sql, oracle, unit-testing, date, dbunit

### The goal

I've got a really strange problem. My goal is to compare a dynamic date in database using dbunit (the database is an Oracle one). This dynamic date is the today date (comparing static date works...)

### The experimentation

To compare date, I use this very simple code :

```
@Test
public void simpleDateTest() throws DatabaseUnitException, SQLException {
    // create a date corresponding to today
    Date today = new Date();

    // load a dataset
    IDataSet expectedDataSet = new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder().build(getClass()
            .getResource("/dataset.xml"));

    // replace [TODAY] by the today date
    ReplacementDataSet rDataSet = new ReplacementDataSet(expectedDataSet);
    rDataSet.addReplacementObject("[TODAY]", today);

    // insert the dataset
    DatabaseConnection connection = getConnection();
    DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT.execute(connection, rDataSet);

    // do a simple query to get some fields, em is the entity manager which uses the same connection as above
    Query q = em
            .createNativeQuery("SELECT ID, MY_DATE FROM MY_TABLE");
    List<Object[]> result = q.getResultList();

    // compare the date with today date
    assertEquals(today.getTime(), ((Date) result.get(0)[1]).getTime());
}
```

With the following dataset :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<dataset>
    <MY_TABLE ID="1" MY_DATE="[TODAY]" />
</dataset>
```

### The problem

I don't know why, but the assert failed ! When comparing the two dates, there is a very few milliseconds difference. The error is something like that :

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<1358262234801> but was:<1358262234000>
```

I don't understand how is it possible to have different dates because they are quite normally the same !
Any clue to understand the problem and how to solve it ?

Comment: Seems some time passed between the calls

Comment: @Quassnoi : the fact is that it references the same Date, so the date, once instantiated, cannot be changed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Oracle Date type doesn't have a resolution of milliseconds, it only has a resolution of seconds.
When saving a time to the database the milliseconds are simply stripped off. When you look at the actual value you see that the last three digits are all zero.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `today` is a `java.util.Date`, the Java `Date` has millisecond precision.  An Oracle `date`, on the other hand, does not have millisecond precision.  So you would expect to lose some precision when you store a `java.util.Date` in Oracle and retrieve it back.

You could store the data in an Oracle `timestamp` column-- that will have millisecond precision.  Or you could strip off the milliseconds from the Java `Date` before writing it to the database.